# ASP.NET MVC How to get certain field of selected object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

For the Controller I need to extract the CustomerID from this selector list.

For page behaviour in javascript, I need to also get the Customer year of birth from the selected Customer object (let's say from field Customer.DOB)

How can I achieve this please?

```
<select id="customerSelector" name="CustomerID">
   <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select Customer</option>
   @foreach (Customer c in Model.Customers)
   {
      // display customers in selector list
   }
   <option value="@c.CustomerID">@CustomerFullName</option>
</select>

<script>
   // get selected customer year of birth
</script>
```

Comment: If you're going to use asp.net-mvc you should embrace [using razor to create your elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: @ErikPhilips will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `onChange` event for the dropdown list and read a data attribute from the selected option as follows using jQuery:

```
select id="customerSelector" name="CustomerID">
   <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select Customer</option>
   @foreach (Customer c in Model.Customers)
   {
      <option data-birthyear="@c.BirthYear" value="@c.CustomerID">@CustomerFullName</option>
   }
</select>
```

then your script would look like:

```
$('#customerSelector').change(function(){
    var birthYear = $(this).find(':selected').data('birthyear');
});
```

note this assumes your model holds some property that represents the customer's birth year. Here, I've assumed that the `Customer` class has a property named `BirthYear` on it. As mentioned in the comments, I'd also suggest using razor HTML helpers to create html elements when using .net mvc